How can i install libraries like Numpy and Abqpy into Rhino8, Grasshopper
Is there anyone who can help me with a problem I can’t solve myself?
I need to install libraries such as Numpy and Abqpy (Abaqus) into Rhino 8, Grasshopper (GhPython)
The problem is mainly with Abqpy.
How can I do that?
I tried to install Abqpy using this github (https://github.com/haiiliin/abqpy), the library is perfectly installed and can be used in Visual Studio. But i do not know how to install the library so i can uses it in GhPython in Grasshopper.
I tried this approach but without success. https://discourse.mcneel.com/t/how-to-install-libraries-like-scipy-into-rhino-8-beta-script-editor/167130/5
Abqpy library in grasshopper python3.9, script folder
Error message from grasshopper

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

You can import libraries with a # requirements: myLib header.
"""Grasshopper Script (With imports)"""
# requirements: numpy, scipy, abqpy==2023.7.2

from abaqus import *
from abaqusConstants import *
from caeModules import *

The above will import abqpy, but this does not mean it will actually interface well with Abacus. You need to make sure your env is properly setup because abqpy is not a standard library but a mechanism to interface with the Abacus api. See Docs
I suggest first troubleshooting your env outside of Rhino 8 to confirm Abacus is appropriately set up in your local Path for access by abqpy.
